# Postman pre request scripts are not executed while performance testing

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

while executing performance tests for the [following](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19cW_82J0wjqnZ7sHN0DywxX_qK7C2R09/view?usp=sharing) collection, pre request scripts are just not executed..

I see no logs, nor any other expected behaviour inducted by the script.

Another strange behaviour is that the scripts are executed if i run the collection in "functional" mode, but not in "performance"

Are you aware if is this a postman bug or something i am making wrong in the the collection configuration?

Tried to modify the scripts, invert execution order, debug the script execution with logs. But the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: have you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the behaviour is intended, so i think the only way would be to configure a script at collection level, so you can execute it at least once per test run